# App ID , Bundle ID and Provisioning Profile Issue

Tags: iphone, xcode, app-store

I have an existing app in the App Store that I am now trying to update for Push Notifications. For the existing app I was using generic provisioning profile with App ID like [some numbers].*

Now since I have to add Push Notifications, I am forced to create new App ID and Provisioning Certificate.

For the new provisioning certificate I created new App ID on the provisioning portal with Bundle Identifier (App ID Suffix) : [some numbers].[my last name]

On iTunes my existing app has Bundle ID  : [my last name]

In XCode in the plist file the Bundle identifier  : [my last name]

My app with push notification now works on my test device, but when I try to submit the update on iTunes Connect, it tells me I have a problem with provisioning profile and fails verification.

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

In itunes for Push Notification was a 2 certificates^ Sandbox and for release. Get sure, for release you have a true Certificate